# How to change the default folder vagrant download box on mac?

Tags: macos, vagrant

It's default to `~/.vagrant.d/boxes/` but I want to move them to my SD card to free up some space. BTW, what's the performance impact of such move? Will it be slow when I run `vagrant up` or it will be slow in many ways?

Answer (score 1):

you can set the [`VAGRANT_HOME`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/other/environmental-variables.html#vagrant_home) environment variable

> `VAGRANT_HOME` can be set to change the directory where Vagrant stores
>   global state. By default, this is set to `~/.vagrant.d`. The Vagrant
>   home directory is where things such as boxes are stored, so it can
>   actually become quite large on disk.